# Why does this angularjs test work in 1.5.x but not in 1.6.x?

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, phantomjs, karma-runner

The following code blocked worked no problem for the last two years in AngularJS 1.4 and 1.5.  However, we recently changed to angularjs 1.6 and the tests fails.  In all angularjs versions that I attempted, the compiled element seems to be correct. (`<h2 class="ng-binding">Bill</h2><p class="ng-binding">Age: 29</p>`)  What seems to fail is the result of `find()`.  In 1.5, `elem.find('h2').html()` returns the expected string.  In 1.6, `elem.find('h2').html()` returns undefined.  I reviewed the changelog, but nothing has help me resolve the problem.  What did I miss?

```
describe('wppicd-child Directive', function() {
    var elem, scope;

    beforeEach(function() {
        angular.mock.module(ngModuleName);
        angular.mock.inject(function($rootScope, $compile) {
            var elemT = ('<wppicd-child ' +
        'child="child">' +
        '</wppicd-child>');
            scope = $rootScope.$new();
            scope.child = {
                name: 'Bill',
                birthday: new Date('April 8, 1988')
            };
            elem = $compile(elemT)(scope);
            scope.$digest();
        });
    });

    it('should have correct title', function() {
        expect(elem.find('h2').html()).toContain('Bill');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I don't know the precise problem, the solution was upgrading PhantomJS from 1.x to 2.x.  We hadn't done that previously because of library conflicts on the CI server which has been resolved. Once upgrading to 2.x, the builds worked again.